# volley or okhttp before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-theme

I need to get a color from my `color.php?id=` using volley or okhttp and set this color:

```
setTheme(colorId);
```

the problem is to set color it need to be before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

my question here is, is it possible to get from the server this color and set this before the super.oncreate? if possible could anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onCreate method you can skip setContentView and then call it when you get a network response. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getColor();
}

private void getColor(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    //do other UI related things...
                }
                ...
            });
}
```

Hope this works for you.